# Formatting numbers in a specific column of a file inplace

Tags: shell, awk, text-formatting

I'm trying to format the `Amount` col to 2 decimal format like `1000` to `1000.00`

I have a sample file like below

```
Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100||
xyz|we||100.1||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
xyz|errt||-230.0||
xyz|ss||234.78||
xyz|we|valid|990.2||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.9||
xyz|we||.9||
xyz|we||.0||
xyz|we||.00||
```

I tried `awk -F"|" '{OFS=FS}''{printf ("%.2f",$4) ; print }' test.csv` which resulted in

```
0.00Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
100.00xyz|we||100||
100.10xyz|we||100.1||
23459900.00xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
-230.00xyz|errt||-230.0||
234.78xyz|ss||234.78||
990.20xyz|we|valid|990.2||
9922.90xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922.9||
0.90xyz|we||.9||
0.00xyz|we||.0||
0.00xyz|we||.00||
0.00
```

Also I want to avoid the header line and replace in the original file.Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/361691) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752530/formatting-numbers-in-a-specific-column-of-a-file-inplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a flaw in your awk code, you print first the modified value of $4 plus the full line

A correct version is like this: `awk -F"|" 'NR<=1{print $0;next}  {{printf($1"|" $2"|"$3"|%.2f|"$5"|"$6"\n",$4)}}' test`

```
$ awk -F"|" 'NR<=1{print $0;next}  {{printf($1"|" $2"|"$3"|%.2f|"$5"|"$6"\n",$4)}}' test
bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100,00||
xyz|we||100,00||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900,00||
xyz|errt||-230,00||
xyz|ss||234,00||
xyz|we|valid|990,00||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
```

you need to print all the fields untouched plus the field 4 modified as you wish.
To not process the first line you test NR and just print the line without modification and continue with `next` to the second line

*edit* i may have a issue with my awk version cause original command and my version dont keep the decimal numbers when present and set them to 0. I guess if should work for you. Something related to my LOCALs i guess.
for exemple `234.78` is turned into `234,00` on my machine.

Another solution from ***Paul_Pedant***'s comment is to change the value of $4 directly and print after :

```
plonky@sd-143012:~/work$ awk -F '|' '{ {OFS=FS} if (FNR > 1) $4 = sprintf ("%.2f", $4); print; }'  test
bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100,00||
xyz|we||100,00||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900,00||
xyz|errt||-230,00||
xyz|ss||234,00||
xyz|we|valid|990,00||
xyz|we|9922.9 paid|9922,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
xyz|we||0,00||
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just one thing is there a way not to explicitly mention all the cols in the `printf` , as number of cols will vary

Comment: Well, you have another variable giving the number of cols for the current line, you can iterate a for loop and build the string to be printed.
But the more standard is your input, the less work to do with awk.

A real solution would be to write a real awk script, using BEGIN/END feature, to make an array where you fill each case with a field. 
In the END section you process the array and print what is required to print from it(ie: not printing empty case, which means the field is missing)

Comment: You can just repair column 4, if you have FS and OFS set. `{ if (FNR > 1) $4 = sprintf ("%.2f", $4); prinf; }`. That keeps all other columns.

Comment: Paul, i upvoted your more elegant solution ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR>1 {printf "%s|%s|%s|%.2f|%s|%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

The `-F '|'` you already have, but is the field separator.

You said you wanted to skip the first line, that can be done with `FNR>1`. `FNR` is the input record number in the current input file. As awk is a line base reader, the `>1` is saying *process after the first line*.

Using `printf` is correct as well, but your syntax was out for the result that you wanted. You can expand to print the whole line as requested.

You did also forget a line return `\n` at the end of the line, which is why you got the odd layout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --csvlite --fs '|' put '$Amount = fmtnum($Amount,"%.2f")' file
```

To modify the file in place, add the `-I` command line switch.

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (née Perl6)**

I would probably do something extremely mechanical using Raku, with explicit `split` and `join` calls. That way you can change to another column separator (e.g. a comma) using the same digit-formatting code:

```
~$ raku -e 'for lines.skip(1) {my @a = .split("|"); .subst(@a[3], sprintf( "%.2f", @a[3] )).join("|").put };'
```

Also, I've written the code to create a `tmp` file that first holds the header, and then append the formatted data lines. Not what you requested--but it works. Also, with this code there's no need to know the total number of columns per line (beyond the column you're trying to format).

Putting it all together:

```
~$ raku -e '.say for lines[0];' < bank.txt > tmp
~$ raku -e 'for lines.skip(1) {my @a = .split("|"); .subst(@a[3], sprintf( "%.2f", @a[3] )).join("|").put };' < bank.txt >> tmp
```

Output:

```
Bank|Branch|Comment|Amount|Extra1|Extra2
xyz|we||100.00||
xyz|we||100.10||
xyz|we|paid for inv# 34VM23-SEP-20|23459900.00||
xyz|errt||-230.00||
xyz|ss||234.78||
xyz|we|valid|990.20||
xyz|we|9922.90 paid|9922.9||
xyz|we||0.90||
xyz|we||0.00||
xyz|we||0.00||
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/